# How would you implement read receipts and unread sorting in Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to find a way to sort posts based on tags, read/unread, and saves, all while showing live likes. I have been through a few iterations of architecture and haven't run into anything that works well.

This will be displayed in an infinite scroll list view on mobile (fast scroll, long lists, render only whats on screen).

First attempt

```
posts <-- onAdd
  {id}
    title: string
    body: string
    tags
      {tag}: bool
    likes: int <-- onValue

users
  {uid}
    read <-- onAdd
      {id}: bool
    saved <-- onAdd/Remove
      {id}: bool
```

This failed because my posts have 10k or more in a list, and on mobile view, it was setting and removing the likes onValue 20-40 times a second during fast scroll, and it was introducing lots of UI jank. Plus, if you scroll down, and then back up, you read the top data twice as far as I know.

I then tried to listen onAdd/Remove/Change to `posts` and that wasn't acceptable because anytime someone liked a post, it was sending a lot of extraneous data.

I also couldn't find any way to sort by unread posts without downloading all of posts and manually ignoring every id in `user/{uid}/read`

Second attempt

```
posts <-- onAdd
  {id}
    title: string
    body: string
    tags
      {tag}: bool

users
  {uid}
    read <-- onAdd
      {id}: bool
    saved <-- onAdd/Remove
      {id}: bool

likes <-- onAdd/Change
  {pid}: int
```

In this example, I was downloading everything and meshing it together in a kind of multiplexer. This actually worked pretty well, I was able to listen efficiently, and merge all these streams into something with a structure like this

```
post
  title
  body
  tags
  read
  saved
  likes
```

This was the most promising, but I underestimated how long Firebase would cache data. And with my list being so long, anytime someone would open the app they would get a firehose of data (1mb or more) that would slow the app down until it was done, and presumably consume a lot of data.

I'm having a real rough time coming up with a method that is cheap and sortable that will work well with an infinite scroll list.

There are many things I am unsure of with pagination.

1) Is it cheaper to set onValue to an entire list, onAdd/Remove/Change to an entire list, or onValue to visible list items and allow the user to scroll through setting and removing listeners?

2) If you are listening to a list from 1-100th entry, and then change the listener from 1-200, do you redownload 1-100 when you reinitialize the listener?

3) If you listen from 1-100, scroll up and trigger a relisten to 101-200, and scroll back down to 1-100, do you download that 1-100 data twice?

4) Is it more expensive to subscribe to posts 1-100 or set up 100 listeners? (Imagine trying to do a favorites only and downloading all the IDs and using them to setup all your listeners)

All of these things are bringing up a lot of uncertainty in the architecture of this app and I'm having a hard time finding answers.

I am confident that I can build any solution, but I feel that I don't understand Firebase enough to architect one.

From what I know, you want shallow queries, and to set listeners as rarely as possible, and to never use onValue when you can do a manual onAdd/Remove/Change combo

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't tied into Realtime Database, you might try applying your architecture to [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) instead (Firebase's newer/other database product). Firestore includes both explicit pagination ([limit/order-by](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)) and implicit pagination ([Snapshot listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)).

There are some structural and billing differences between the two platforms that you should look into, but it sounds like Firestore might be a better fit for your project as presented.

Comment: Hello! Maybe I am misunderstanding your answer, but I believe Realtime Database has the same limit/order-by operation and snapshot listeners.

Comment: I'm more familiar with Firestore, but I don't believe they work the same in both systems. As an example, a Firestore listener only returns changes to a result set since the previous snapshot, while a Realtime listener gives you the full result set each time.

Comment: Point of interest, I was testing Realtime Database the day before and they only send deltas over the wire with onValue listeners.